# debian 9 - dovecot roundcube sieve

Tags: debian, dovecot

I'm having troubles understanding what I'm doing wrong with getting sieve to work for the purpose of using roundcube's filtering plugin.

I followed the guide at https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/ to setup the encrypted mailserver with sql-based virtual users.

Roundcube I installed from tarball, and functions perfectly with the exception of creating filters.  When I try to create a filter, I get a slide-up notification that it's unable to communicate with the server.  It seems fair enough, somewhere seive and dovecot aren't quite friends yet.

The roundcube part is probably irrelevant at this point.  I'm not familiar enough with this to know where to start troubleshooting nor what to look for.

Any assistance will be much appreciated

netstat -plnt shows port 4190 listening by dovecot
iptables -L -v -n | grep 4190 shows the ipv4 port is open
dovecot -n reports:

```
# 2.2.27 (): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.16 ()
# OS: Linux 4.9.0-12-amd64 x86_64 Debian 9.13 ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
postmaster_address = postmaster at nostalgicmail.com
protocols = imap lmtp sieve sieve
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  process_min_avail = 1
  service_count = 1
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/nostalgicmail.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
  driver = static
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to write out a narrative on exactly how I solved my problem. Hopefully it helps others, and lays out some new tidbits that can be carried over for future use.

I seen a post elsewhere about debug logging, then watch syslog.

vim /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf

```
#mail_debug = no
mail_debug = yes
```

tail syslog, restart dovecot, then login to roundcube

tail -f /var/log/syslog

service dovecot restart

~click, point, login to email~

I found something interesting in syslog...

```
Jan 24 06:40:22 hwsrv-753880 systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Jan 24 06:41:22 hwsrv-753880 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<username@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=2607:5500:3000:1385::2, lip=2607:5500:3000:1385::2, mpid=31064, TLS, session=<+Cv2vKS5xIMmB1UAMAAThQAAAAAAAAAC>
Jan 24 06:41:22 hwsrv-753880 dovecot: imap(username@domain.com): Debug: Effective uid=5000, gid=5000, home=/var/vmail/username@domain.com
Jan 24 06:41:22 hwsrv-753880 dovecot: imap(username@domain.com): Debug: Home dir not found: /var/vmail/username@domain.com
```

A lovely home dir not found message.  It says debug beside it, which indicates that you won't see this unless debug is enabled.  I cd'd over to /var to take a look... and /var/vmail/ didn't exist at all!  Hmm...

https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/  is dovecot's documentation on where mail should be stored.  It also tells me:

*Mailbox autocreation
Dovecot in the 1.x era created mailboxes automatically regardless of whether mail_location was set. In 2.x autocreation only gets triggered if mail_location is correctly set.*

I'm using virtual users via SQL, and that might change things some.  I kept poking around dovecot documentation, and ran across Home Directories for Virtual Users at https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/home_directories_for_virtual_users/  Remembering the correctly set bit from above, I had to take a look at he current effective settings of dovecot, and compare with the Directories for Virtual Users doc page.

dovecot -n    *This shows you what dovecot actually uses (effective) as it's settings*

My current configuration had mail going to a location that didn't match the documentation.  I wasn't sure of the internals of dovecot, so I decided I should make things match the doc as closely as I possibly could.  Not knowing the internals, I probably took the scenic route on some things.

mkdir /var/vmail

chown -R 5000:5000 /var/vmail    *I don't know what user goes to UID and GID 5000, and don't really care.  It's what Dovecot wants (look at the log above, you'll see it)*

grep -rnw '/etc/dovecot' -e 'mail_location'    *I don't know where in the sea of config files the variable is set.  I also don't know if it's in multiple places, so I use this grep to find all files in /etc/dovecot that contains the mail_location string.*

```
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.orig:13:# path given in the mail_location setting.
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.orig:24:#   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.orig:25:#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.orig:26:#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.orig:30:mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.orig:56:  # mail_location, which is also the default for it.
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:13:# path given in the mail_location setting.
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:24:#   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:25:#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:26:#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:30:# ~this one is working mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:31:# mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/mail
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:32:mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%u/mail
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:58:  # mail_location, which is also the default for it.
/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext:116:#   mail - Mail location (overrides mail_location setting)
/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext.orig:115:#   mail - Mail location (overrides mail_location setting)
```

*(sidenote, if you how to read the above... skip this.

the way to read all that is the first part is the filename, then the line number, then the actual text on that line.  with that information you could issue vim +24 /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf to go to the spot in the file you need to fiddle with.)*

I don't remember where I read it, but somewhere it stuck out in my head that dovecot doesn't play well at all with relative directories, so I knew I needed to set mail_location using exact path. Reading the doc-block above the variable, I came up with  mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%u/mail

I restarted dovecot again, and the syslog tail that I still had running from earlier now flashed something about home dir not found, creating with standard permissions.  Directly after that, then home dir created, blah blah. After that magic display of verbosity, I seen something miraculous about copying sieve rules to home dir.  I logged in to roundcube, and everything worked!  I set dubug back to off, restarted dovecot again, felt proud, and let my ego swell a little.

At the end, sieve was indeed configured correctly.  Roundcube was configured correctly.  Dovecot was working, and I followed the guide exactly.  I finally busted out the documentation, took about an hour of investigation, and found the problem to be related to a filesystem path.

Proof-positive that no matter how stringently you follow a guide, documentation still reigns supreme.  I feel like a lot of people have gotten so used to instant gratification that we forgot the number 1 rule of any *UNIX system... **RTFM**